# How i can add button to main menu not inside message

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

How to add button to main menu behind "**Mark all as read**"

[image]

instead of showing button inside email body read document but it doesn't help me to find solution,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** get your add-in icon displayed in any place you like. The add-in controls are defined by manifest and displayed in predefined locations of particular client (Outlook Web, Outlook desktop for Windows or Mac, Mobile). Up to developers (Microsoft team) to define the place where the add-in controls will be displayed.

EDIT:

There are two places where add-ins may appear in the client interface. This depends on what type of add-in you have created. There are *command add-in* and *contextual add-in*. Both of them will appear somewhat in the space of the message view anyway. The following are examples of where they appear withing the interface ...

[image]

And for web view ...

[image]

To read more on Outlook add-ins Extension points got to [Outlook Add-ins overview article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/#extension-points).

Comment: is there any way to make it show with public view instead of inside email ? anywhere else will be fine for outlook web

Comment: @MokhAkh I have edited my answer, please have a look. As I mention there is no way to display the add-in controls anywhere else other than predefined by client spots. There are two of them, depending on type of the add-in, but both in the message view. This is because the Outlook add-ins are working with single item and should enreach the user experience when working with this item.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature you requested is not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.